# Обновление значения в поле через время

Tags: php, mysql

Здрасть всем, у меня такая поблема, не могу написать такой код, если бензин меньще 100 , делать функцию которая через каждые 3 минуты будет увиличивать поле бензин на 1 ,т.д пока не получиться 100 лтр. как это сделать, если не понятно могу еще раз объяснить ...

Answer (score 2):

Для этого обычно делается очередь событий, причем те события, которые происходят по времени можно вынести в отдельную очередь (для микрооптимизации).
Очередь событий может быть глобальной (для всего сервера) или локальной (для отдельной гонки).
Я рассмотрю случай локальный- потому что в случае браузерных гонок это оптимальное решение.

- Бензин стал меньше 100- помещаем событие в очередь например в таком виде: ТекущееВремя+ВремяЗадержки, НазваниеСобытия, IDигрокаДляКоторогоСобытиеДолжноПроизойти
- При каждом обращении любого участника гоники к серверу извлекаем из очереди все события время которых меньше или равно текущему времени и выполняем их.
- В событии пополнения бензина было бы логично проверить, что бензин меньше 100 (игрок мог заюзать какой-нибудь итем), и если после прибавки бензина он все равно меньше 100, то выполняем первый пункт снова- помещаем событие в очередь.

Comment: впервый слышу такое.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 2):

Можно в крон записать скрипт, который будет изменять каждые три минуты.

Или, если человек сидит на сайте, то он него посылать запросы каждые 3 минуты.

Или записать в базе время последнего обновления. При посещении, вычислить сколько времени прошло с посл. посещения. Поделить на 3 и получившееся прибавить к текущему значению бензина. Если сумма больше 100, оставить 100, если меньше - получившееся.